# How to add to / amend / consolidate JRuby Profiler data?

Tags: jruby, profiler

Say I have inside my JRuby program the following loop:

```
loop do
  x=foo()
  break if x
  bar()
end
```

and I want to collect profiling information just for the invocations of `bar`. How to do this? I got so far:

```
pd = []
loop do
  x=foo()
  break if x
  pd << JRuby::Profiler.profile { bar() }
end
```

This leaves me with an array `pd` of profile data objects, one for each invocation of `bar`. Is there a way to create a "summary" data object, by combining all the `pd` elements? Or even better, have a single object, where `profile` would just add to the existing profiling information?

I googled for a documentation of the JRuby::Profiler API, but couldn't find anything except a few simple examples, none of them covering my case.

**UPDATE** : Here is another attempt I tried, which does not work either.

Since the `profile` method initially clears the profile data inside the Profiler, I tried to separate the profiling steps from the data initializing steps, like this:

```
JRuby::Profiler.clear
loop do
  x=foo()
  break if x
  JRuby::Profiler.send(:current_thread_context).start_profiling
  bar()
  JRuby::Profiler.send(:current_thread_context).stop_profiling
end
profile_data = JRuby::Profiler.send(:profile_data)
```

This seems to work at first, but after investigation, I found that `profile_data` then contains the profiling information from the last (most recent) execution of `bar`, not of all executions collected together.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution, though I have the feeling that I'm using a ton of undocumented features to get it working. I also must add that I am using (1.7.27), so later JRuby versions might or might not need a different approach.

The problem with profiling is that `start_profiling` (corresponding to the Java method startProfiling in the class Java::OrgJrubyRuntime::ThreadContext) not only turns on the profiling flag, but also allocates a fresh ProfileData object. What we want to do, is to reuse the old object. `stop_profiling` OTOH only toggles the profiling switch and is uncritical.

Unfortunately, `ThreadContext` does not provide a method to manipulate the `isProfiling` toggle, so as a first step, we have to add one:

```
class Java::OrgJrubyRuntime::ThreadContext
  field_writer :isProfiling 
end
```

With this, we can set/reset the internal `isProfiling` switch. Now my loop becomes:

```
context = JRuby::Profiler.send(:current_thread_context)
JRuby::Profiler.clear
profile_data_is_allocated = nil
loop do
  x=foo()
  break if x
  # The first time, we allocate the profile data
  profile_data_is_allocated  ||= context.start_profiling
  context.isProfiling = true
  bar()
  context.isProfiling = false
end
profile_data = JRuby::Profiler.send(:profile_data)
```

In this solution, I tried to keep as close as possible to the capabilities of the `JRuby::Profiler` class, but we see, that the only public method still used is the `clear` method. Basically, I have reimplemented profiling in terms of the `ThreadContext` class; so if someone comes up with a better way to solve it, I will highly appreciate it.